# How to insert python variables inside query in Memgrpah?

Tags: python, memgraphdb

I need to execute the following query:

```
CREATE (m: Temp {val1: <variable>})
```

I know there exists `save_node` functionality but I don't want to use that.
I tried the following syntax but it didn't work

```
connection.execute("CREATE (m: Temp {{val1: variable}}})
```

This seems to work only if the variable is a for loop iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a quatation mark at the end of the command as well as qurly brackets around
`variable`.
Here is an example:

```
 from gqlalchemy import Memgraph

 print("Connect")
 memgraph = Memgraph()

 print("Create a node")
 variable = 100
 memgraph.execute(f"CREATE (m: Temp {{val1: {variable}}});")
```